# Books covering the last chapters of Ahlfors' Complex Analysis in more detail

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Can you people suggest some good texts for Complex Analysis? I already have
**Complex Analysis: An Introduction to The Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable** by Lars Ahlfors. but it seems too dense sometimes and skips a lot of steps.

I am specifically looking for a book that covers the material from the later chapters of Ahlfors' book.

Comment: Complex Variables and Applications https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Variables-Applications-Brown-Churchill/dp/0073383171. This book is a standard undergraduate complex variable text. It might seem easy to read because the exposition is very clear. You don't need the newest edition.

Comment: You can try Complex Analysis by Stein & Shakarchi or Complex Function Theory by Sarason. Are you an undergraduate or a postgraduate?

Comment: Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering... Solution manual is also available... nice book with applications....

Comment: Well I am undergrad but I have already done the undergrad and now taking the grad course. So yeah, a book for postgrad complex is I think what I need.

Comment: I would suggest that you go for Stein & Shakarchi then.

Comment: Here is a transition book https://www.amazon.com/Complex-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387950699/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1485012193&sr=8-9&keywords=complex+analysis

Comment: Those kind of teacher's notes are very good [1](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~wang838/notes/complex.pdf) [2](http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/mauras/complex-aa1213.pdf) [3](http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/cpx.pdf) [4](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22complex%20analysis%22%20%2B%22cauchy%20integral%20formula%22%2B%20%22maximum%20principle%22)

Comment: You've the lectures from YouTube *Analysis of a Complex Kind*, from the official channel of the professor **Petra Bonfert-Taylor**. On the other hand I don't know what are the last chapters of Ahlfors. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Complex variables and Applications by Churchill and Brown is a very good option as @Jacky Chong mentioned in the comment. Apart from that I found **Complex Analysis** by **Theodore W. Gamelin** a decent read and quite exhaustive in nature. Also you can have a look at **Complex Analysis** by **Joseph Bak and Donald J. Newman**. Both of the above mentioned books are published by Springer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I studied my complex analysis in this book. I liked it much.

http://www.springer.com/us/book/9781461269670

Answer (score 0):

Endre Pap, Complex Analysis through Examples and Exercises, Kluwar Texts in Mathematics, Springer, 2013.

A. K. Kapoor, Complex Variables - Principles and Problem Sessions, World Scientific Publishers, 2011

Student friendly books with several examples and problems.